# How best to pass a reference to a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Given the following code:

[example.h]

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    bool method (MyClass &object);
};

[example.cpp]

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}
bool MyClass::method (MyClass &object) {
  try {
      object.name = "New Name";
      std::cout << "Name: " << object.name << " " << object.address << std::endl;
      return true;
  }
  catch (...) {
      return false;
  }
}
```

[test.cpp]

```
#include "example.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass myC;

    myC.address = "address";
    bool quest = myC.method(myC);
}
```

What is the difference between the way I've called `myC.method` in `main` above, and this alternative way of doing so:

```
MyClass *myC = new MyClass(); 
bool quest = myC.method(*myC);
```

Which is better and why?

Comment: Which is better : an apple or a hammer ?

Comment: You might want to note that there's no need to have `MyClass::method` take a `MyClass& object` -- when you call it with `myC.method()`, you can already access `myC` from `method` using the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you can send the same value but simply stick with current code is better since it's without pointer dereference and `new`. You need to take care of `delete`'ing the object once you are finished with it, which I don't think you need here.

And it's better to use `MyClass &object const` in the `method` function so that the reference passed in doesn't get changed.

Comment: thx a lot for your answer!! :) I would like to ask you how if i have the following example MyClass *c = new MyClass; try {//code } catch(int i) {} where should I put delete c? inside of try or after catch? THX@

Comment: @sunset You should ask that as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Using new (and dynamic memory allocation in general) is better if you need the object to last longer that the scope of the function it's being called in. If it's just for a known duration the `MyClass myC;` local scope version is best (because it's simpler to read and maintain).

When using `new` your object "myC" won't be deleted until you call `delete`.

However if you just define it as a local object it will get deleted when it goes out of scope:

```
{
 MyClass myC;
 myC.DoSomeStuff();
} // It'll be destroyed here
```